# How to fix aspx web scraping returns empty string?

Tags: jsoup

I am trying to use jsoup to obtain two values from an ASP page.
Code is as follow:

```
package webscraper;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class WebScraper 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {       
        Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://ime.co.ir/Futures_fix/Futures_MarketWatch_FIX_fa.aspx?Code=GCTR90").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.78 Safari/535.11").post();
        Element ele = doc.getElementById("BP1");
        Elements Final = ele.getElementsByTag("b");
        System.out.println("Final Text: " + Final.text());
    }
}
```

Where I am looking for tag **b** there is no value or I am not pulling it properly.
The value at that tag updates every 10 seconds. element **BP1** returns fine.
Can anybody spot any errors here and point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't method name `getElementsByTagName()`?

Comment: HI, thanks for your response, not sure what you are referring to but method name is right.  Couldn't find a method by the name "getElementsByTagName(). I get everything back from my functions but the value is empty because website is sending its source rather than the source after all fields are populated.  Therefore tag b is empty. Maybe the page is somehow restricted in that regard.

Comment: Actually just figured those fields might be hidden.  I am kinda of new at scrapping any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what you're looking for exactly but if I open the web page I see some **b** tags populated. If you write the downloaded page down to disk what do you get?

Comment: HI, I get everything except any of the numbers.  Basically my program is getting high and low prices of the table to create a point and figure chart. The easiest way to see this is if you try to use the excel query for web you see what comes up. Thats exactly what I get as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Selector way](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
doc.select("#BP1").select("b");
```